# What function is used when selecting a color in a Customize buffer?

Tags: customize, colors

I don't like the function that Customize uses to select color. It spawns a new buffer that messes up window configuration, and is also difficult to search.

I want to replace this function with the following:

```
(defun helm-insert-color-hex ()
  "Insert the hex value at point for the color selected via helm"
  (interactive)
  (insert (apply 'color-rgb-to-hex (color-name-to-rgb (helm-colors)))))
```

How can I do this? I can't seem to find what that "Choose" button does (for example, when setting a foreground color for some face)

Comment: I couldn't understand your original question, so I rewrote it. If my new text isn't accurate, you can roll-back the change or make further edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function used to display the list of colors is `list-colors-display`. This function is actually called from the `color` widget, so that's the code you'll need to work with. Emacs widgets are documented in their [own manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/widget.html), available from Emacs via `C-h i widget <ret>`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the question and answer!